# How to reformat a .csv file with in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

Just a quick question, with pandas `to_csv()` function I saved a pandas dataframe as a .csv file with this structure:

In:

```
df.to_csv(output_file, sep = '|')
```

Out:

```
|id|column2|column3
0|id_1|bla bla bla bla|more strings
1|id_2|bla bla bla bla|more strings
2|id_3|bla bla bla bla|more strings
....
n-1|id_n|bla bla bla bla| more strings
```

The problem with the previous file is the format, as you can see there is a bad column at the left side of the .csv file:

```
|id|
0|
1|
2|
....
n-1|
```

From the start, I tried to just drop that column which actually does not have a name by doing:

```
df.drop('',axis=1)
print list(df.columns.values)
['id', 'column2', 'column3]
```

However, it did not worked. How can I restructure the previous .csv file into something like this with `to_csv()` function?:

```
id|column2|column3
id_1|bla bla bla bla|more strings
id_2|bla bla bla bla|more strings
id_3|bla bla bla bla|more strings
....
id_n|bla bla bla bla|more strings
```

**update**

With the answer of @piRSquared I tried to reformat the csv file as follows:

```
print list(df.columns.values)
return df.to_csv(output_file, sep='|', index_col=1)[['column1','column2', 'column3']]
#return df.to_csv(output_file, sep = '|')
```

Nevertheless, I got this:

```
['id', 'content', 'POS-tagged_content']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 48, in <module>
    preprocess_files(input_file, output_file)
  File "script.py", line 39, in postag_pandas
    return df.to_csv(output_file, sep='|', index_col=1)[['column1','column2', 'column3']]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: You just want to trim the index, correct?

Comment: You mean `df.set_index('id', inplace=True)`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I just want to drop the column that does not have any header. I allready tried with:`df.set_index('id')`. However, it did not worked.

Comment: You mean `df.drop('',axis=1)`

Comment: In order to avoid confusion, you should get in the practice of providing sufficient code to produce the state you currently have a question about.  Please use this as a guide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry are you after `df.to_csv(file_path, index=False) `

Comment: The problem is that it is actually a lot of code... for that reason I tried just to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.set_index('id')
```

Where `df` is your dataframe

---

#### Edit

IIUC

What you've provided is a the text from a csv file and you are importing it into a pandas dataframe.  It's confusing when you say:

> How can I restructure the previous dataframe into something like this?:

I believe you've confused what is a dataframe and what is a csv.

A csv it text or a file with text that is to be parsed.  Typically, this text is separated by commas.  (**C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues)

a dataframe in a pandas/python context is a python object.

All that said, I believe you meant to ask:

How can I import a csv with this text such that I don't get the first column.

```
text = """|id|column2|column3
0|id_1|bla bla bla bla|more strings
1|id_2|bla bla bla bla|more strings
2|id_3|bla bla bla bla|more strings
n-1|id_n|bla bla bla bla| more strings"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='|', index_col=1)[['column2', 'column3']]

print df
```

Looks like:

```
              column2        column3
id                                  
id_1  bla bla bla bla   more strings
id_2  bla bla bla bla   more strings
id_3  bla bla bla bla   more strings
id_n  bla bla bla bla   more strings
```

From here you can save to a csv like this:

```
df.to_csv('./mycsv.csv')
```

produces

```
id,column2,column3
id_1,bla bla bla bla,more strings
id_2,bla bla bla bla,more strings
id_3,bla bla bla bla,more strings
id_n,bla bla bla bla, more strings
```

Which is what you said you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the help!, it did not worked. Any other idea of how to just drop the index that does not have any header?.

Comment: Note that it aint a pandas df, it is actually a .csv file.

Comment: Thanks and sorry... I confused the .csv file with the pandas dataframe. I omitted the fact that this is while I am using `to_csv` function. I would like to reformat when I am saving as a .csv file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, probably I was not clear. I added more details to my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
print df.to_string(index=False)
```

This will print your dataframe without the indexes.

```
>>> print df
     id          column2       column3
0  id_1  bla bla bla bla  more strings
1  id_2  bla bla bla bla  more strings
2  id_3  bla bla bla bla  more strings

>>> print df.to_string(index=False)
   id          column2       column3
 id_1  bla bla bla bla  more strings
 id_2  bla bla bla bla  more strings
 id_3  bla bla bla bla  more strings
```

Comment: Thanks for the help andy, note that it is actually a .csv file

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a blank string for one of the columns, you can [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop) it:

```
In [47]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2), columns=['','asd'])
df

Out[47]:
                  asd
0 -0.911575 -0.142538
1  0.746839 -1.504157
2  0.611362  0.400219
3 -0.959443  1.494226
4 -0.346508 -1.471558

In [48]:
df.drop('',axis=1)

Out[48]:
        asd
0 -0.142538
1 -1.504157
2  0.400219
3  1.494226
4 -1.471558
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!, I all ready tried just droping the index, but I got this esxception: `ValueError: labels [''] not contained in axis`

Comment: Can you post the output from df.columns.tolist() and df.info()

Comment: Sure I also try that:`print list(df.columns.values)`:`['id', 'column2', 'column3]`

Comment: Thanks for the help Ed, I added more details to my question.